# Patient with knee injury / knee pain

Tags: knee, physiotherapy, tens, bursitis

I am undergoing physiotherapy for my knee injury (pain in the kneecaps) and aching soreness on the sides of my knees (bursitis). Part of my therapy is the use of TENS (Transcutaneous electrical nerve stimulation) and FES (Functional Electrical Stimulation). Some physiotherapists apply TENS first, then FES afterwards. But one therapist make me do both TENS and FES at the same time. Which is the correct or better approach?

Comment: Interesting question. Though, I think it would be worse explaining what TENS and FES mean. These are not common abbreviations and explaining what they mean would probably help in making your question clearer. Thank you. Best regards. M. Arrowsmith.

Comment: TENS is Transcutaneous electrical nerve stimulation. FES is  
Functional Electrical Stimulation. Thank you. I appreciate a response to my question.

Comment: Actually I was thinking that you should edit your question and provide those explanation directly in your question... Concerning your question, I haven't found some evidence based papers regarding the use of TENS +/- FES in physiotherapy for your specific indications. But I hope someone will find something to provide you an accurate answer. Good luck. Best regards. M. Arrowsmith

Comment: Many thanks M. Arrowsmith! Appreciate your help. Warm regards.